# Como faço para mostrar informações de um determinado local, visualizando no modo responsivo, no celular?

Tags: html, google-maps, maps, layout-responsivo

Adicionei o *iframe* de um determinado lugar no meu site, mas as informações do local, e sugestão de rotas, não aparecem quando visualizo no modo mobile, vendo no celular.

Aqui está o jeito que aparece no celular:

[image: Printscreen com um ponto no mapa]

Aqui o jeito que quero que apareça quando visualizado no celular:

[image: printscreen com um card informativo]

As configurações no *style* do mapa não essas:

```
<style>
.embed-container { 
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
   height: 0; 
   overflow: hidden; 
   max-width: 100%;
} 

.embed-container iframe, 
.embed-container object, 
.embed-container embed {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

**iframe:**

```
<iframe 
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3714.5088877509456!2d-48.50192088548785!3d-21.40923378579348!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94b93967f68b2d9f%3A0x4fd97015c3d8cff5!2sGrande+Hotel+de+Taquaritinga!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1512313658033" 
    width="100%" 
    height="450" 
    frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como alterar isso, faz parte da responsividade do `iframe` do Google Maps.

O mapa só irá exibir as informações completas se a largura em que ele ocupa for igual ou maior do que *400 pixels*. **Logo**, isso não está diretamente ligado ao dispositivo ser celular ou não.

Abra num iPhone 4 na posição *paisagem* (480x320 pixels) que as informações aparecerão completas. **Agora**, se girar para a posição *retrato* (320x480 pixels), só aparecerá o nome do local.

Comment: Muito obrigado por esclarecer isso amigo, eu realmente fiz o teste em modo paisagem e as informações apareceram mesmo.

Comment: @JohnnyRodrigues Se achou a resposta útil, não deixe de marcar ✔

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá tente o seguinte:

no css

```
.container-map{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

agora no no html coloque a iframe dentro da div `.container-map` e altere a largura para auto ao invés de 100% ficando assim:

```
<iframe 
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3714.5088877509456!2d-48.50192088548785!3d-21.40923378579348!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94b93967f68b2d9f%3A0x4fd97015c3d8cff5!2sGrande+Hotel+de+Taquaritinga!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1512313658033" 
width="auto" 
height="450" 
frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen>
```

e veja se resolveu! abraço!!

Comment: Não deu certo man, tentei mas as informações não aparecem mesmo, valeu ai!